# How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError in a Xamarin application?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently reinstalled Visual Studio en Android Studio on my machine. After compiling a hello world like application, I get the following error in visual studio:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0    App200*

I don't understand it since it does not refer to any part of my project and I think all the dependencies are correctly installed in the Android SDK manager. Hopefully, someone can help me based on the following information in the submitted screenshots. It may be relevant to know that I do not have such an issue when using Android Studio in building a Java based Android app. So I do not know what to do since the error is java based.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me in understanding and solving this issue.

Comment: Last screenshot, wrong Java version, you need 1.8+

Comment: As a second note, ensure you nuke your `obj/bin` folders as it will keep an `sdks.cache` of your last JDK location.